# Cypress test with session, fails with "401: Unauthorized"

Tags: javascript, cypress

Cypress test with session, fails with "401: Unauthorized" on line
`cy.visit('/admin/people/create');`

**Why am I getting this error?**

file cypress.json

```
"experimentalSessionSupport": true,
```

file with test code:

```js
describe('Session testing', () => {
  const login = (name,password) =>{
    cy.session([name,password],()=>{
      cy.visit('/', {
        auth: {
          username: 'username',
          password: 'password',
        },
      });
  
      // Filling field email to 'Log in' form
      cy.get('#edit-name--2').type(name);
      // Filling field pass to 'Log in' form
      cy.get('#edit-pass--2').type(password);
      cy.get('#edit-submit--2').click();

    })
  }

  beforeEach(()=>{
    login('username','password');
  })
  
  // Creating user with 'Organisation responsible' role
  it('Create organisation responsible user', () => {

    cy.visit('/admin/people/create');

  });

});
```

Comment: Could you please move the block ```cy.get('#edit-name--2').type(name); cy.get('#edit-pass--2').type(password); cy.get('#edit-submit--2').click();```into the ```it``` instance and check what happens?

Comment: Got a **ReferenceError**:

password is not defined


line: `cy.get('#edit-pass--2').type(password);`

Comment: Oh yeah, you probably need to define it first as ```let password = "thatismyPW"```. What I am hoping to find out is whether the ```cy.visit('/admin/people/create')``` works after a "manual" login